# Submit a dynamically created table

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamically-generated

Im trying to submit a dynamically created table but so far without any luck..
Can i do this?
Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Tzj9T/1/) . For testing purposes ive put an email to post the form, later i will post it into a php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to submit an input or select field, you have to provide name attribute. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tzj9T/2/

Good Luck!

Comment: another thing similar to this. because i have create many select elements ,how can i send also the i value in order to have something like sdsd1, sdsd2?

Comment: If you set the names of the select fields sdsd1, sdsd2, ... you will get in your email sdsd1=value1, sdsd2=value2 and so on. Is this what you ment?

Comment: i cant set the name for sdsd1 and sdsd and so on cause i dont know how much select elements i have cause they are created dynamically. if you look at my code im giving different id's to every new created element based(id: "AlarmTypeSelect" + i ) . I want to do something similar to this with the select name